# Start Menu search is no longer functional and the Cortana (SearchUI.exe) process is using a lot of resources

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, windows-search, cortana

Recently I moved my desktop PC to a new place and for some reason the Windows start menu search is no longer functional.

I usually tap the Windows key and type to open up most programs. Now, after I type, the search just stays blank. Sometimes the loading/progress at the bar at the top of the search window will flicker from the left side.

- Example of the Search Window

[image]

I've also noticed the Cortana process in task manager seems to using an excessive amount of resources. Specifically it looks to be the `SearchUI.exe` process.

- Cortana in Task Manager

[image]

I'm not really sure what's changed. I updated my Nvidia GPU drivers recently, but rolling back didn't change anything. My SSDs and HDD are accessible in file explorer, so I don't think they got knocked loose.

If anyone has any ideas, or knows where to grab some more information I'll gladly provide it. I'd rather not reinstall Windows, but if that ends up being the only solution, so be it.

Comment: From admin elevated command prompt, run `sfc /scannow` reboot, and test afterwards.Quick potential first step for troubleshooting 101.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Looks like it found corrupt files it couldn't fix. Looking in the log seems like there's quite a few from Windows-Defender-Management-Powershell and some Start Menu directories "owned twice or has its security set twice".

Comment: From admin elevated command prompt, run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` be patient and let it finish, restart, and then test to see if things are back to normal.